# IocLookupException: E_IOC_LOOKUP_FAILED: Cannot resolve "Adonis/Lucid/Database" namespace from the IoC Container

Tags: typescript, error-handling, ioc-container, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

Getting this error while saving data into postgres using insert query via ADONISJS commands feature.
Followed up the official documentation but not able to solve this.

```
    import Database from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Database';
 public async run() {  
    {
      try {
        console.log('Starting fetching data from Coingecko')
        const response = await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list', {
          params: {
            include_platform: true,
          },
        })

        if (true) {
          const coinsData = response.data
          await this.saveToDatabase(coinsData)
          console.info('Data Saved Successfully!')
        } else {
          console.error('Error while saving the data!')
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`)
      }
    }
  }
 private async saveToDatabase(coinsData: any[]) {
    for (const coin of coinsData) {
      await Database.table('coinsInfo').returning('id').insert({
        id: coin.id,
        name: coin.id,
        symbol: coin.symbol,
        platforms: coin.platforms,
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a minimal working example, the errors you are getting aswell as what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

install the dependency:

```bash
npm install @adonisjs/lucid
```

and call

```bash
node ace invoke @adonisjs/lucid
```

sometimes this error is just forget to invoke, this worked for me when i start to learn about adonis
if dont work, tell me and i can help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).